# Add a non-system confirm popup on node add/edit

Tags: 7, ajax, forms, workflows

I want a custom confirmation popup to come up when someone wants to save a new node or update an existing one. Of course, the form only submits/saves info if the user clicks Yes. As it is now the popup only fires on the first click (of course it should fire as many times as necessary), and the form still submits regardless of whether one clicks Yes or No. It should only submit when the user clicks Yes. If the No button is clicked the popup should disappear and the user can go on working on their node. If they finish working and click Submit again, the confirm popup should reappear and work as expected.

I am using [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) on my form, and I only want this functionality for certain workflow states (IDs 2 and 5), not all of them. For the JS confirmation popup itself I want to use [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/).

It seems like one needs to do an AJAX callback for this, so here is what I have in my `hook_form_alter` function. The first part adds the AJAX callback to the submit buttons, and then the inline JS should call the popup. Lastly, the AJAX callback just returns a string.

What have I done wrong here? I would be thankful for any help.

```
// The part of my hook_form_alter where I give the submit button AJAX functionality
$form['actions']['submit']['#prefix'] = '<span id="wf-wrapper">';
$form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '</span>'; 
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
        'event' => 'mousedown', 
        'callback' => 'confirm_save',
        'wrapper' => 'wf-wrapper',
        'prevent' => 'click',
        'method' => 'replace'
);
$form['workflow_button_js'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<div id="buttonjs"><script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {

        // override the default confirmation dialog behavior
        Drupal.behaviors.workflowConfirm = {
            attach: function(context, settings) {                               
            Drupal.ajax["edit-actions-workflow-5"].options.beforeSerialize = function(element, options) {
            $("#edit-actions-workflow-5").once("mousedown", function () {
                    vex.dialog.confirm({
                        message: "Have you chosen all the necessary options?",
                        callback: function(value) {
                                if(value === false){
                                    return false;
                                }
                        }
                    });
                });
                }
            }
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script></div>',
);

// AJAX callback, just returns a string

function confirm_save($form, &$form_state){
    return 'submit';
}
```